# Converting the volumetric flow rate, into 2D

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, dimension-theory-analysis

Suppose there is a fluid flowing in a tube with some flow rate. Let's say: $10cm^3s^{-1}$.

Now suppose I'm going to model this problem in 2D, by assuming that the tube is a rectangle.  I was wondering whether there is a way to convert the volumetric flow rate into the 2D model.
Ideally, some value with the units $cm^{2}s^{-1}$.

If the cross sectional area of the tube is: $A$ and the width of the rectangle is $W$, I do have a very rough estimate as $\left(\frac{10}{A}W\right) cm^{2}s^{-1}$, which is dimensionally correct. But I would like to know your opinion as well.